# R: sliding a query overy a long sequence

Tags: r, time-series, euclidean-distance

Suppose I have a long sequence and a query sequence:

```
LongSeq <- c(3,5,2,6,5,4,8,9,6,2,4,6,1,3,6,9,5,10,9,6,3,7,8,2)
QuerySeq <- c(6,2,4)
```

The goal is to find a sub sequence from the `LongSeq` with same or similar sequence to the `QuerySeq` using Euclidian distance for example. Wrote a for loop that slides one step at a time and calculates the Euclidian distance but this is slow, especially when `LongSeq` is really long. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this in `R` or a suitable `R` package.

Comment: You can't avoid looping unless you create large intermediate objects to operate on which might not be feasible with large vectors; e.g. like `order(sqrt(colSums((t(embed(LongSeq, length(QuerySeq))[, length(QuerySeq):1]) - QuerySeq) ^ 2)))`. What exactly have you tried that is slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform the long sequence into a matrix:

```
LongSeqMx <- as.matrix(
  data.frame(p1 = LongSeq[1:(length(LongSeq) - 2)],
             p2 = LongSeq[2:(length(LongSeq) - 1)],
             p3 = LongSeq[3:(length(LongSeq))]))
```

Then, you can apply k-nearest-neighbor algorithms:

```
FNN::get.knnx(LongSeqMx, matrix(QuerySeq, nrow = 1))
```

This example returns the indexes and Euclidean distances to the 10 nearest points.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses `rollapply` in the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)

dist <- function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x-y)^2))

w <- length(QuerySeq)
dists <- rollapply(LongSeq, w, dist, y = QuerySeq, fill = Inf, align = "left")

least.ix <- seq(which.min(dists), length = w)
least.seq <- LongSeq[least.ix]
least.dist <- dist(least.seq, QuerySeq)
```

giving:

```
> least.ix
[1] 9 10 11
> least.dist
[1] 0
> least.seq
[1] 6 2 4
```